# Azure Synapse Pipeline Script Activity: "Incorrect Syntax" Error when using script parameters

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

I'm currently trying to write a script that will be run by an Azure Synapse pipeline to initialize my serverless database. As part of that I need to use a parameter so that I can switch out the storage account easily between the prod and non-prod versions of synapse. For some reason I can't get the script parameter to work. Here is my SQL query:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.external_data_sources WHERE name = 'bronze_data')
BEGIN
    CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE bronze_data WITH (LOCATION = @storageAccountUrl);
END
```

Then I define a new script parameter like this:
[image]
However when I run the pipeline I get the following error: errorCode 2011, Incorrect syntax near '@storageAccountUrl'

If I hardcode the location everything works just fine. I am able to make it work by using dynamic content and just using pipeline parameters but that's a lot messier to use (no syntax highlighting and often you have to do string concatenation).

Am I missing something here or is there some kind of bug in Azure?

**Edit:**
I just found this post that is the same error: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1005399/azure-synapse-script-parameter-for-external-table. Their solution works if I use pipeline parameters but it still doesn't pull from the script parameters.

Comment: Wrap ‘@storageLocationURL’ in single quotes?

Comment: I tried that and while it doesn't error out the created external data source ends up with a location of the literal string: @storageLocationURL instead of the actual URL.

Comment: Ok, try creating the sql script using concat or string interpolation instead.

Comment: Try by a Declare a variable and the pass the valu to that variable.

Comment: String concatenation is a workaround to get things going (although a pretty ugly one especially if it's a complex query). Although it's still using pipeline parameters not script parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I tried the below script in Script activity, I got same error.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE AzureStorage5 with 
( 
    TYPE =Blob_storage,
    LOCATION = @storageaccount,
    CREDENTIAL =AzureStorageCredential1
);
```

[image]

[image]

**AFAIK**, Script activity parameters might be only used as filters for the data like the below script.

`select * from sample2 where Id=@Id`

They may not be used for the above scenario or for passing the table while selecting from it like `select * from @table_name`.

So, for the location in the above script, create a **set variable activity with your location value** before the script activity and use that in SQL script with `concat()` or **String interpolation** as suggested in the comments.

Comment: Ahh ok, I wish they were clearer on that or actually stated that somewhere. String interpolation seems to be a decent solution (as opposed to string concatenation which can get really ugly really fast).  My team did open a ticket in Azure about this so if I get a direct answer I'll update here as well.

Comment: I asked the same question on the Microsoft Learn platform and they confirmed that it seems like script params are only to be used as you mention: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1251505/azure-synapse-pipeline-script-activity-incorrect-s?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1237328#newest-answer-comment